# Blackman-Harris Windowing via Command Line

Tags: bash, shell, window, sox

I am trying to window an audio file converted to a specrogram and would like to use a Blackman-Harris window.  Currently I am using the Hamming window available in sox like this:

```
sox wav_16kHz/1.wav -n trim $start_time .025 spectrogram -w Hamming -o spec_Hamming.png
```

Where I create my steps of 40% of the window size (set at 25ms) in a loop in bash.

Does anyone know of a decent implementation for Blackman-Harris?  Preferably one which can be used via command line since all of my normalization and steps are done in shell script.

Comment: ever find something that works for you?

Comment: unfortunately, no. I ended up with good results with the Hann window but I did want to test Blackman Harris.  All the implementations I found are in C and/or not particularly easy to adapt to my pipeline.  If someone knows of a good one I am all ears still :-)

Comment: I am in a similar situation. I will use sox as a first version for my pipeline and see how it works.  After that, numpy/scipy have some good fft with window functions....or the lib pyfftw which I have not used yet.

Comment: sounds good. let me know what you come up with.